# wc_get_product_terms() throws "Notice: Undefined offset: 0"

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I currently have debug mode enabled in `wp-config.php`. I'm trying to loop through all the products in a certain category on my store.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'product_cat' => 'scotch-whisky',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I am then attempting to loop through the products and get a list of brand names. There might be five products with the brand name "Apple", however I am curating a list of brands so I only want "Apple" to appear once in the array.

To do that I loop through the products and check if the brand name is in my list, if it is I skip it, if not I add it to my list.

```
<?php

$distilleries = Array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $attr = wc_get_product_terms(get_the_id(), 'pa_distillery');
    print_r($attr);
    if (
        in_array($attr[0], $distilleries) === false &&
        strlen($attr[0]) !== 0
    ) {

        array_push($distilleries, $attr[0]);

        ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/product-category/scotch-whisky/?filter_distillery=<?php echo strtolower($attr[0]); ?>">
                    <?php echo $attr[0]; ?>
                </a>
            </li>

        <?php

    }

endwhile;

?>
```

The problem appears on some iterations where I try to access `$attr[0]` in the if statement and get the following error:

> Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/www.something.com/123/public_html/wp-content/plugins/brand-list/list.php
>   on line 87
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/www.something.com/123/public_html/wp-content/plugins/brand-list/list.php
>   on line 88

I run a var dump on $attr[0] and $attr[0] is NULL. How can I stop this error from appearing or is there even anything I need to do or worry about?

Many thanks,

Jethro

Comment: You need to check if `$attr[0]` exists using `isset()`, or that `$attr` isn’t `empty()`, before attempting to use `$attr[0]`, even in an `if` condition.

Comment: Yes this solved the notification. Amazing! Thanks for the quick help!!